# Use Backbone model default if a attribute value is null

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a backbone model and collection. In the model, the default attribute values are defined:

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: { 
        name: "mark",
        middle: "-"  
    }
});

var People = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Person
});



var collection = new People();

collection.add({name: "paul", middle: null});

console.log('collection is ');
console.log(collection);
```

I want the default value for "middle", which is "-", to be taken if "null" is passed in for the attribute "middle". However, "null" overrides the default instead. How do I do this? The jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CZwnk/28/)

Comment: Model defaults are for when you don't have a value being set. null is a value. This would work as expected if you didn't set a middle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest way probably is to add a [`parse`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse) method and normalize the data:

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    name: 'mark',
    middle: '-'
  },
  parse: function (payload) {
    return {
      name: payload.name || undefined,
      middle: payload.middle || undefined
    };
  }
});

collection.add({name: "paul", middle: null}, {parse: true});
```

#### Note that when the data is returning from the server via `fetch` it will automatically go through `parse` and there's no need to call pass the option flag.

You could do it either on the model level or at the collection level.

Answer (score 1):

check for value when initialize

```
initialize: function() {
  if (!this.get("middle") || $.trim(this.get("middle") || '') === '') {
    this.set({"middle": this.defaults.middle});
  }
},
```